# Tkinter Frame enlarges when adding widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a simple Tkinter app that has a main frame with two smaller frames on the sides, like so:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("MyApp")
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1,weight=4)
root.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='NSEW')
button1 = tk.Button(frame1,relief=tk.FLAT,text="button")
button1.grid()

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='NSEW')
button2 = tk.Button(frame2,relief=tk.FLAT,text="button")
button2.grid()

frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
frame3.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky='NSEW')
button3 = tk.Button(frame3,relief=tk.FLAT,text="button")
button3.grid()
```

But if I add more widgets to one of these frames:

```
button4 = tk.Button(frame3,relief=tk.FLAT,text="button")
button4.grid(row=0,column=1)
button5 = tk.Button(frame3,relief=tk.FLAT,text="button")
button5.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

then frame3 enlarges itself (instead of shrinking, as I understand it should do), ignoring the 1-to-4 specification of the columnconfigure. I've been googling like crazy but found no answer, so any ideas will be more than welcome. Thanks.

**Update:**
Thanks for the answers. I wanted to add a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation to post an image. If weights don't prevent a column from being overexpanded, how can I make sure the frames will keep their initial proportions despite how many widgets I add to them. Should I turn grid_propagate off or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each frame is initially the size it need to be to contain all the widgets.  The weights determine the allocation of extra space if you stretch the window.  They also determine the rate at which different widgets compress if you shring the window.  In your case, the second frame looses space 4x faster.

Comment: Ok, but the three buttons here compress to a total width less than the frame's initial width. If the windows stays the same, why is then the frame expanding, allocating unused space, when there's no need for it? I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: You columnconfigure for root only, not for frame3.  frame2 is columncontigure weight=4 and you don't change anything in frame2.  I don't know if this helps or not, as I am not sure what you want as an end result.

Comment: I described what happened when I ran your code and changed the size of the window, both bigger and smaller than the initial size.

Answer (score 0):

`columnconfigure` affects how widgets use *extra* space, they aren't absolute column widths. A column with a weight of 4 can easily be larger or smaller or the same size as a column with a weight of 1 or 2.

From the official documentation for the grid command:

> The -weight option (an integer value) sets the relative weight for
>   apportioning any extra spaces among columns. A weight of zero (0)
>   indicates the column will not deviate from its requested size. A
>   column whose weight is two will grow at twice the rate as a column of
>   weight one when extra space is allocated to the layout.

When you put items in a frame, by default the frame will attempt to resize to exactly fit its contents. That means that if you add a widget to a frame, that frame will grow unless there's already extra space inside the frame for the widget.